# plural/singular controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

I know that using plural for controllers name is the right way in Ruby, but in some cases using singular for controllers name is more appropriately. For example

```
http://foobar.com/admin/login/
http://foobar.com/admin/dashboard/
http://foobar.com/profile/
```

I think you get what I mean.
So which are the best practices of using singular for controllers names ?

Any example will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the whole scaffolding, for example you probably have no admin model, then you can just generate a controller with a singular name.

`rails g controller admin`

Then, you need to take care of the routing.

`match 'admin/login' => 'admin#login'`

Answer (score 0):

Rails favours convention over configuration, so it means that controllers are ALWAYS using plural, table names also, whereas models are always using singular, with an uppercase at the beginning.

I would strongly advice you to stick to these conventions, that's best practice and in the foundation of the Rails framework

Comment: I know that but it will be ugly to see http://foobar.com/logins/ or http://foobar.com/profiles/ etc.